# How to change x-axis label of graph to be multiples of 10?

Tags: python, plotly

I am using plotly library to plot my line chart.

Currently my x-axis has a limit from 0 to 10G (10 Billion) with equal divisions / intervals.

```
fig.update_xaxes(visible=True, range=[0,10000000000])
```

Is there any way I can change the x-axis label to increase in multiples of 10 like the image below instead of having equal intervals?

[image]

Comment: Try ```range=range(0,10000000000, 10)```

Comment: do you need something like logarithmic plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for built-in options:

```
fig.update_xaxes(type="log")
```

...will give you this:

[image]

...instead of this:

[image]

#### Complete code:

'

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode="markers", x=df["gdpPercap"], y=df["lifeExp"] ))

fig.update_xaxes(type="log")
fig.show()
```